# manipulate python variable inside a GTK action listener

Tags: python, checkbox, gtk

I'm trying to an action listener that is attached to a checkbox button.  My goal is to toggle the variable value ( 0 or 1 ) whenever the checkbox is checked/unchecked.

I come from a C background and am fairly new to python.  I've also been reading up on global variable but I cannot seem to grasp it.

I will do an example in C first :

```
//#includes

int test; //i could say public int test but it is public by default

int foo()
{
    test = 1;
    return test;
}
void main()
{
   test = 0;
   print (foo);
}
```

Some example python code is below.

```
class someRandomClass: 

    def on_checkbutton1_toggled(self, widget, data=None):
        if test == 0:
            test = 1
        if test == 1:
            test = 0

    def __init__(self):
        global test
        test = 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = someRandomClass()
    gtk.main()
```

Executing this python code and clicking on the checkbox throws an
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'test' referenced before assignment

I've tried creating the global variable outside of a function but still inside the class - the same method as the example C code.

Comment: The easy fix is to add `global test` at the top of the `on_checkbutton2_toggled` function.

Comment: Right as you posted this I had it running.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer fairly quick after posting :

```
def on_checkbutton1_toggled(self, widget, data=None):
    global test
    chkbtn1 = self.builder.get_object("checkbutton1")
    print "BUTTON CHECKED -",chkbtn1.get_active()
    if chkbtn1.get_active() == 0:
        test = 0
    if chkbtn1.get_active() == 1:
        test = 1
    print test

def __init__(self):

    global test
```

With this I am able to print out the value of test throughout my other listeners.  If anyone else wants more code feel free to let me know.